# Parse complex csv data using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have csv data ([csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQSa3.png)) like:

```
id,247341,247341
company,    1 800 FLOWERS COM INC,  1 800 FLOWERS COM INC
ticker, FLWS,   FLWS
financial year end (month), 6,  6
industry code,  103002, 103002
indicator,  Share Price,    Common Shares Outstanding
2011-11-04, 2.72,   65046.232
2012-02-06, 2.89,   65065.558       
2012-05-04, 3.04,   64788.687
```

I did not understand after reading this data how can I format the output data? I want output data like this:

```
id:247341
company:1 800 FLOWERS COM INC
ticker: FLWS
financial year end (month):6
industry code:103002
indicator:{
                   #Based on date
    Share Price:2.72; Date:2011-11-04
    Share Price:2.89; Date:2012-02-06
    Common Shares Outstanding:65046.232;Date:2011-11-04
    Common Shares Outstanding:65065.558;Date:2012-02-06

}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried first?

Comment: I did not understand how can i  work on it, where share price has value on different date .But my csv file has no date column each row contain date and this date contain value on different indicator.please help @OneRaynyDay .

Comment: Is that output the entire output or does it repeat somehow when there is more data in the CSV file?

Comment: Yes it is repeat when more data comes on csv file @MartinEvans

Comment: It would help if you gave a fuller example (in CSV text format rather than an image, then it can be copy/pasted).

Comment: So your CSV file does not contain any commas?

Comment: @MartinEvans post updated

Answer (score 2):

Using the text you have provided for your CSV file, you could use the following approach:

```
import csv

def write_block(f_output, block):
    if block:

        f_output.write("""{}:{}
{}:{}
{}:{}
{}:{}
{}:{}
{}:{{
          #Based on date
""".format(
    block[0][0], block[0][1], 
    block[1][0], block[1][1], 
    block[2][0], block[2][1], 
    block[3][0], block[3][1], 
    block[4][0], block[4][1], 
    block[5][0]))

        for price in block[6:]:
            f_output.write('    {}:{};Date:{}\n'.format(block[5][1], price[1], price[0]))
        for price in block[6:]:
            f_output.write('    {}:{};Date:{}\n'.format(block[5][2], price[2], price[0]))

        f_output.write('\n}\n')

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    block = []

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row):
            if row[0] == 'id':
                if block:
                    write_block(f_output, block)
                block = [row]
            else:
                block.append(row)

    write_block(f_output, block)
```

Take care to ensure the indenting is preserved when copying the script.

In effect it uses the CSV library to read each row in the file until another `id` line is found. This is then treated as a `block` and written to an output file.

I suggest you add `print(block)` to understand how this works.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up and down buttons to select the answer as the accepted solution.